# How can I display all 31 days on the month of march

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, date

I only have **Day 1, 3, 9 and 14** on my **database**. All i want is to **display is day 1 - 31 on the month of march**

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate all the days of a month:

```
with recursive march_days as
(select convert('2022-03-01', date) as d
union all 
select date_add(d, interval 1 day)
from march_days
where d < '2022-03-31')
select * from march_days;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=826f2a6901c09abbbf0c649edc6d82cf)

Answer (score -1):

In php you can get the days with a for loop.

```
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) {
    # Do your date things here.
}
```

That is just a basic counter, without more to go on from your project, code sample etc, then it is unlikely that we will be unable to give you better direction on this.